# Powershell - Read CSV contents, copy file from a network drive to local machine

Tags: powershell, csv, windows-10

I am currently in the process of restructuring a Windows server file directory and need to bulk rename over 10,000 files all in different folders but most have duplicate filenames (e.g 0001.pdf, 0002.pdf)

I have written a Powershell script to help me do this but I am having some trouble with the execution. 
The script reads a csv file (export of all the files in the folder structure - export.csv) then creates the variables `$OldFilename` & `$NewFileName`. The variables are then used to locate the old file location and copy it to a new destination using the `Copy-Item` command for each row in the CSV.

Code

```
$csv = import-csv c:\tmp\test.csv
$csv | foreach-object {
  $OldFileName =$_.OldFileName
  $NewFileName = $_.NewFileName
}
$csv | ForEach-Object {
      $OldFileName =$_.OldFileName
      $NewFileName = $_.NewFileName

Copy-Item $OldFileName -Destination $NewFileName   

}
```

CSV is formatted as such

```
OldFileName,NewFileName
"X:\Folder1\0001.pdf","C:\temp\File0001.pdf"
"X:\Folder2\0001.pdf","C:\temp\File0002.pdf"
"X:\Folder3\0001.pdf","C:\temp\File0003.pdf"
```

Code does not error when run but files do not appear.

A `Write-Output` displays the correct file path but a `Write-Host((Get-Item $file).length/1MB)` does not retrieve the files size which leads me to believe there is an issue with the variable!?

Something I need to add?

Many Thanks

Jonny

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct permissions provided to PowerShell when it runs?

Comment: I ran the script as another user that didn't have any permissions but it did error out. However the one I using does not :|

Comment: Your code works for me.  Your `Write-Host` is using `$file`, which is not defined in your script.  That could be your problem.

Comment: could be timing on the network as well, you may want to try robocopy